# How to check HAM license status - India - Grade One License?

Tags: license, india

I got my HAM Radio License (Grade-One) License issued on 2005 year (New Delhi, India). Unfortunately Date of Termination of the license is missing. Tried reaching Helpdesk via E-Mail but not much help.

1. Is my Amateur Radio license still valid? If not, how to get it renewed?
2. My residence address got changed. How to update new address?
3. Is there an online portal from Department of Telecommunication (India) where license can be renewed?

[image]

Comment: Could you please furnish your call sign?                                     73

Comment: My call sign is vu2syi

Comment: Thanks, OM Santanu. 73.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For renewal of Amateur Radio Transmitting licence the following are required:

- A letter requesting renewal of licence
- Copy of original license along with copy of last renewed intimation (if it has been renewed before)
- Proof of age
- Proof of address

Licence fee Rs. 1000.00 for a 20 year license and Rs. 2000.00 for a Life Time License. Payments to be made through the Non Tax Receipt Portal (NTRP).

A copy of the online payment receipt is to be enclosed with your other documents.
A large self-addressed envelope (no stamps required) also to be enclosed.

Note:
WPC does not charge any fee for licence renewals beyond 80 years of age. The applicant only needs to submit an application requesting renewal along with a copy of the licence. The licence is then renewed for a period of 10 years.

It can be renewed for another 10 years after the licencee completes 90 years of age.

All these to be sent by courier to

Asst. Wireless Advisor to GOI,
608 Sanchar Bhavan, 20 Ashoka Road,
New Delhi-110 001.

More information at

http://arsi.info/faq/

Comment: Hi Nandu, appreciate your help. I referred to the link and got clarified. I think as per stackexchange standard, the answer should not contain link to refer considering the link may be down in future. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help, Santanu!

Comment: @user6835509 is right, it's best to give a little information along with the link, so that if the link rots then the information is still useful.  Please do that, and I'll upvote you.

Comment: Done! Thank you rclocher3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an Online Portal nowadays https://saralsanchar.gov.in
You can also visit [https://itshamradio.com](https://itshamradio.com/) for more information on Indian Amateur Radio Community.

Comment: Hello Saquib, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Hi Saquib, thanks for the help. I got my HAM Radio license renewed via online using saralsanchar.gov.in portal. Thank you!! :)